# Oracle Time Difference between SYSDATE and Date From Column

Tags: oracle, date, difference, oracle12c

I'm very new to Oracle. I have this problem, I got 365 days difference while these 2 dates' difference is are only one day.

This is my SYSDATE Query Output:

> SELECT to_date(SYSDATE,'yyyy-MM-dd') FROM LOGINRECORDS

`15-OCT-11`

This is my date from column Query Output:

> SELECT to_date(LoginDate,'yyyy-mm-dd') FROM LOGINRECORDS WHERE LoginRecordId = '1000001'

`15-OCT-10`

And when I run this query :

> SELECT (to_date(SYSDATE,'yyyy-MM-dd') - to_date(LoginDate,'yyyy-MM-dd')) difference FROM LOGINRECORDS WHERE LoginRecordId = '1000001'

I got this:

`365`

This is my table description :

```
CREATE TABLE LOGINRECORDS
(
    LoginRecordId NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY START WITH 1000000 INCREMENT BY 1,    
    LoginDate DATE,
    patientUserId NUMBER
)
```

Hope you guys willing to help, Tq in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This expression:

```
to_date(SYSDATE, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

doesn't make sense.  `SYSDATE` is *already* a date.  So, this expression converts `SYSDATE` to a string, using whatever local settings are on your system.  Then, it converts *that* result to a date, using the format `'yyyy-MM-dd'`.  For many values of the local settings, this would simply fail.

If you want the difference, then do something like this:

```
SELECT (trunc(SYSDATE) - trunc(LoginDate)) as difference
FROM LOGINRECORDS
WHERE LoginRecordId = '1000001';
```

Note that in Oracle, the `DATE` data type has a time component, hence the use of `trunc()`.  If you know that `LoginDate` has no time component, then that part does not require `trunc()`.